# Can genetic algorithm（GA） be used in the optimization model with thousands of decision variables?

Tags: python-3.x

I have built a single objective optimization model, but there are thousands of decision variables in the objective. Can this situation be solved by genetic algorithm? If yes, how long is the running time?

Now I have used the genetic algorithm to solve it, but the results obtained are very poor, and none of them meet the constraints. I also searched some papers and materials, but I haven't found a suitable solution at present.I hope technical friends can answer my doubts.Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: 每条染色体长度不同，有的甚至可以达到4000多个基因